# Trying to work out a custom CSS org chart; my divs won't sit right

Tags: html, css

Basically, I'm trying to set up a basic org chart. The idea is that there are 7 divs that hold the level that an employee is on the org chart. Essentially, the Director would be a level1 employee and he would be located at the top (in row 1). The next two down, the assistant to the director and the deputy director, should be at a fixed height a certain distance down from the director; however, because these 2 elements are in a div together as a ul, they are stacking rather than centering and sitting beside each other.

Here's a link to the codepen and the sample code is below: http://codepen.io/jacob_johnson/pen/Oymvap

```
/* HTML */
<div class="content">
    <figure class="org-chart cf">
        <ul class="dcca">
            <li>
                <ul class="level1">
                    <li><a href="#dir"><span>Director</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="level2">
                    <li><a href="#ad"><span>Assistant to the Director</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#dd"><span>Deputy Director</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </figure>
</div>

/* CSS */
.level2 > li > a {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

.level2 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is the second row (the assistant to the director and deputy director) to be inline with each other and centered. I can achieve one or the other but I cannot figure out how to do both. I have looked at many other topics but I just can't figure it out...

Comment: You still want them to be in an unorder list?

Comment: If you don't mind them being in the same <ul>, why not just do something like this? <li><a href="#ad"><span>Assistant to the Director,Deputy Director</span></a></li>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your situation correctly, I think this would work well as a solution. Remove the fixed positioning and top space from .level2 and add:

```
ul.dcca{
  text-align:center;
}
ul.dcca li{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: You don't need `position: relative` and `width:100%` is the default anyways. I would target `.dcca ul` just to make it apply to all levels.

Comment: Good catch the easiest way would be to just add text-align: center to ul.dcca and then set all of the li to be display:inline-block

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to start using bootstrap for any css design issue.

The best fix I can think of will be:

change:

```
<ul class="level2 ">
```

to

```
<ul class="level2 list-inline"">
```

And add a reference to bootstrap

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Inside `<head>`

Hope this helps

Comment: This is total overkill for what the question is asking.

Comment: I don't want to use Bootstrap for a simple CSS fix.